# ObjC: Subclass a class whose @interface is inside a .m file

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, runtime

I am trying to subclass a class whose @interface and @implemetation are buried inside of another class' ".m" file in order to restyle some of the views declared within.  The superclass is a cocoapod, which I am unable to modify without forking the repo, which I am really trying to avoid doing.  Is there any clever/hacky way to pull this off, or is it simply impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all honesty, I fail to see why forking would be a bad idea or why you would want to avoid it. That's the entire point of forking, modifying the code to fit your need more and perhaps later merge it back if the community finds it useful as well.

You can try to hack around this by redeclaring the class or whatever, but that implementation would be far more fragile than you having a fork which you have full control over (including merging any upstream changes). I think this is more related to a mental block of thinking that a fork becomes "your" code and "your" responsibility, while in reality it is just as much to maintain as it would be to keep the hacky version working across changes to the 3rd party code.